# How to remember which function is concave and which one is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, mnemonic

I always struggle to remember when a function is convex and concave:

[image]

**Do you have a particular trick to help you remember this**?

My trick is based on the Spanish phrase "No cabe", pronounced `nô ˈka.βe`, which sound just like "concave". "No cabe" means it does not fit. Thus, whilst you can put something into a convex function (e.g. think of a bowl), you cannot put something into a concave function. Hence the relation.

I am curious on what other, perhaps more efficient methods people use.

Comment: I personally prefer "conv**ex** **ex**ponential function" and conclude that the logarithm is concave.

Comment: If you know the standard English meaning of the words convex and concave, you can remember that for a convex function it is the epigraph that is convex, and for a concave function it is the epigraph that is concave. Failing that, the "cave" mnemonic mentioned by @SeanRoberson seems unforgettable.

Comment: In Swedish, which probably luchonacho doesn't know, one can connect *convex* with *växande*, meaning *growing*. Here, *vex* and *väx* sound the same. A convex function doesn't have to be growing, but if it's differentiable, then the derivative is growing.

Comment: @md2perpe: And "konk**av**" matches "**av**tagande" (=decreasing) too! :-)

Comment: Det är så sant så!

Comment: Doubling down on the first comment. "$e$ to the $x$ is convex" (which even sort of rhymes) is how I remember it. Just remembering one example of a convex function is enough.

Answer (score 14):

I think it just depends on how you learn.

When I took calculus, we didn't use "concave" and "convex" - rather, we (and the AP exam) used "concave up" and "concave down." I still use these as a grad student.

One can also remember that concave functions look like the opening of a **cave**.

Comment: Why not use *convex up* and *convex down*, though?

Comment: @k.stm Who knows. I just went with it.

Comment: To this I might add "concave up, like a cup" and "concave down, like a frown" if you have more difficulty remembering.

Comment: @BobKrueger I did something similar when dealing with curve sketching and derivatives - concave up, smiley face, $f''(x) > 0$. Concave down, frowny face, $f''(x) < 0$.

Answer (score 5):

In English, there is a great trick from [David MacKay's recommended book on information theory](http://www.inference.org.uk/itprnn/book.html): Just keep pronouncing the word "convex" as "convec-[smile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsD8b.png)" and "concave" as "conca-[frown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxgt5.png)" and the direction of the mouth of the corresponding smiley will tell you what the graph of the function looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think of it as they both are in a smiling contest, concave smiles with the v and convex with the v and x. However, the fact that the function convex smiles more makes the concave sad.

Answer (score 0):

conVex - V looks like the convex function :)

Comment: But concaVe....

Comment: @F.A. But Co⋂cave... ;)

Comment: @TheQuark There is a "n" also in "convex"

Comment: @robertspierre Yes, thus my actual (different) answer to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4701856/265509)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remember 1 of them, conCAVE, it is already in the word it is a cave hence the shape :-)

Comment: Duplicate of @Sean Roberson answer

Answer (score 0):

For consistency and coherence between curve shapes in a $(x,y)$ plane and the shape of the surface of lenses, it is better to relate the terms with the sign of the curvature $\partial^2 y/\partial x^2$:

- concave = negative curvature: $\partial^2 y/\partial x^2 < 0$ (thus: downward curve or hollow surface)
- convex = positive curvature: $\partial^2 y/\partial x^2 > 0$ (thus: upward curve or domed surface)

concAve <-> negAtive

conveX <-> $+$ (rotated X)

And when you look at a surface, the equivalent of the y-axis is the axis of your gaze, oriented away from you.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught in my language that concave = the one I can't pour coffee ("káva") in. Anyway it doesn't help that with lenses and mirrors this is the other way around.